# Set values to the items in DropDownListFor in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this:

```
<div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Language, new SelectList(new[] { "string1", "string2", "string3", "string4" }, "string1"))%>
</div>
```

I want the strings to have some values. Example, string1, to have a value=1, string2: value=2, etc. How to do this?

Comment: You could create a `Dictionary<string, int>` then a select list like `SelectList(dictionary, "key", value)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117604/implementing-dropdownlist-on-asp-net-mvc-3-from-viewmodel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
new List<SelectListItem>(){ new SelectListItem{Text="item1", Value = "valuer1", ... }
```

or use SelectList but pass into it Dictionary or List<> of custom objects.

Answer (score 0):

**Static Binding**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to the Training Courses...";
            List objcourses = new List();
            objcourses.Add("Asp.Net");
            objcourses.Add("MVC");
            objcourses.Add("WCF");
            objcourses.Add("WPF");
            objcourses.Add("C#.Net");
            ViewBag.Courses = new SelectList(objcourses);
            return View();
        }
    }

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
Index
@using(@Html.BeginForm(“Index”,”Home”,FormMethod.Get)) {
Courses List; @Html.DropDownList(“Courses“)
}
```

**Dynamic Binding**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            private MovieDBContext db = new MovieDBContext();
            var GenreLst = new List();
            var GenreQry = from d in db.Movies
                           orderby d.Genre
                           select d.Genre;
            GenreLst.AddRange(GenreQry.Distinct());
            ViewBag.Courses = new SelectList(GenreLst);
            return View();
        }
    }
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
Index

@using(@Html.BeginForm("Index","Home",FormMethod.Get)) {

Courses List; @Html.DropDownList("Courses")
}
```